# Capture emoji in javascript

Tags: javascript, parsing, emoji

I have to write a module in javascript that can detect emoji and replace each of them with a div tag with the link to an image.

(Emojis are strings of the form :) :-) etc )

The problem is I have several hundreds of them and trying to write a regular expression to capture all of them is not a good idea.

Is there a way to do this given I have a hashmap with the keys are the emoji strings and the values are the hex values. (all emojis are within a range)

Thanks!

EDITED: So maybe the way I stated the problem was not clear. Imagine you have a dictionary of 100000 words, each of 4-5 characters. And a stream of lines, each line contains 100 - 150 characters. How would you find the words in the lines?

Comment: why is [string.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) not good enough? It can work without regular expressions.

Comment: "Strings of the form `:)`, `:-)`, etc." are _emoticons_, not _emoji_. Emoji are special characters in a [specially-designated code point range](http://www.unicode.org/faq/emoji_dingbats.html).

Comment: Maybe you could use a loop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Javascript strings are, unfortunately, sequences of **16-bit** unsigned integer codepoints, normally representing the UTF-16 encoding of a Unicode string. Consequently, Unicode characters outside the BMP (codepoints starting at `U+10000`) are represented as surrogate pairs, each of which is two "characters" long. That's visible in regular expressions; if you want to match, for example, `U+1F623` ("PERSEVERING FACE"), you need to match `\uD83D\uDE23`.

While annoying, this is not totally impractical. Ranges are still pretty easy to match. For example, assuming you believe emoji to be the range `U+1F300...U+1F64F`, which is most of but not all of the characters listed in the emoji transcription data at http://www.unicode.org/Public/UNIDATA/EmojiSources.txt, then you could use the regex:

```
/\uD83C[\uDF00-\uDFFF]|\uD83D[\uDC00-\uDE4F]/
```

To compute those codes, you need to understand the mapping from a non-BMP Unicode codepoint to two surrogate characters. It's not that complicated :) First, you subtract `U+10000` from the Unicode codepoint (the designers of UTF-16 chose to avoid wasting codespace on codepoints which already fit in 16 bits). That leaves you with a 20-bit number, since the largest valid Unicode codepoint is `U+10FFFF`. Now, you need to split that 20-bit number into two 10-bit chunks. The high-order 10 bits are added to `U+D800` to form the first surrogate code, and the low-order 10 bits are added to `U+DC00` to form the second surrogate.

Using the PERSEVERING FACE example:

```
U+1F623 => 0F623       (subtract 0x10000)
        => 0000 1111 0110 0010 0011  (in binary)
        => 00 0011 1101, 10 0010 0011 (two 10-bit chunks)
        =>  03D,  223  (back to hex)
        => D83D, DE23  (add D800 to first and DC00 to second)
```

A "simple" way to get your computer to do these computations, if you have `bash` and the `iconv` utility, is:

```
printf $'\U1F623\U1F3A9' |
iconv -f utf8 -t utf16le | hexdump -e '8/2 "%04x " "\n"'
```

(I split that into two lines for display, but you can just type it as one line. You can put as many codes as you want into the string passed to `printf`.)

Comment: JS strings may be UTF-16, but is there anything that says that the _regex engine_ works on that basis, as opposing to matching on actual code points?

Comment: @ChrisJester-Young: The ECMAScript standard says that a string is a sequence of unsigned 16-bit integers. Although strings are assumed to be UTF-16 sequences, they are not required to be; that is, invalid sequences do not throw an error. The grammar does not provide a mechanism for inserting a unicode codepoint outside of the BMP, although a conforming implementation may accept programs encoded in UTF-8, converting non-BMP characters into two 16-bit surrogates as per UTF-16. Specifically, the two codes which make up a surrogate pair are individual characters, including for regex matching.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly you're avoiding regex because you haven't found one that works properly so far. You can try this one, maybe it works.

```
/(?:[\u2700-\u27bf]|(?:\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]){2}|[\ud800-\udbff][\udc00-\udfff]|[\u0023-\u0039]\ufe0f?\u20e3|\u3299|\u3297|\u303d|\u3030|\u24c2|\ud83c[\udd70-\udd71]|\ud83c[\udd7e-\udd7f]|\ud83c\udd8e|\ud83c[\udd91-\udd9a]|\ud83c[\udde6-\uddff]|[\ud83c[\ude01-\ude02]|\ud83c\ude1a|\ud83c\ude2f|[\ud83c[\ude32-\ude3a]|[\ud83c[\ude50-\ude51]|\u203c|\u2049|[\u25aa-\u25ab]|\u25b6|\u25c0|[\u25fb-\u25fe]|\u00a9|\u00ae|\u2122|\u2139|\ud83c\udc04|[\u2600-\u26FF]|\u2b05|\u2b06|\u2b07|\u2b1b|\u2b1c|\u2b50|\u2b55|\u231a|\u231b|\u2328|\u23cf|[\u23e9-\u23f3]|[\u23f8-\u23fa]|\ud83c\udccf|\u2934|\u2935|[\u2190-\u21ff])/g
```

I hope this will help you